# Testing an Android library with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, testing, groovy, robolectric

I created a library which can be used in an Android environment. At the moment it contains *Plain Old Groovy Objects*, there are no Android dependencies. Tests for those POGOs run without problems.

To extend the library's features I create classes which inherit from Android classes or rely on them, I want to test those too. Of course tests should be part of the library and should not be implemented as a part of an Android application project which includes the library.

I know that an application can be tested with the help of [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) and it works pretty well but I see no possibility of using it without a whole Android application behind it.

*Is there a way to test a library with Android dependencies and Robolectric?*

I am using Android Studio 1.2.

Comment: What version of Robolectric do you use? I wrote several tests for library project without having application itself. But it was android library not plain java (groovy). You might go just with android gradle plugin itself that can mock android.jar with default returns. I'm not sure how good it suits for you

Comment: @EugenMartynov For the latest application I used Robolectric 3.0 RC2 but making it work with version 2.x and as an Android Java library is fine too. I just need some basic setup to start with.

Comment: At https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/tree/library you can find basic sample for a library module tested by robolectric. Do you have some issues with your project setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is a good choice for you. For example if you wrote a class that inherits from the DialogFragment you can see if it behaves correctly:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ProgressDialogFragmentTest {
private static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "KEY_PROGRESS_MESSAGE";
private static final String TEST_MESSAGE = "test message";

@Test
public void argumentsContainExpectedKey() {
    //given
    ProgressDialogFragment fragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(TEST_MESSAGE);

    //when
    boolean containsExpectedKey = fragment.getArguments().containsKey(MESSAGE_KEY);

    //then
    assertTrue(containsExpectedKey);
}

@Test
public void argumentsContainsValidMessage() {
    //given
    ProgressDialogFragment fragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(TEST_MESSAGE);

    //when
    String actualMessage = fragment.getArguments().getString(MESSAGE_KEY);

    //then
    assertEquals(TEST_MESSAGE, actualMessage);
}

@Test
public void createdDialogIsProgressDialog() {
    //given
    ProgressDialogFragment fragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(TEST_MESSAGE);
    FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment);

    //when
    Dialog dialog = fragment.getDialog();

    //then
    assertTrue(dialog instanceof ProgressDialog);
}

@Test
public void dialogIsHiddenBeforeRunShowMethod() {
    //given
    ProgressDialogFragment fragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(TEST_MESSAGE);
    FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment);

    //when
    ProgressDialog dialog = (ProgressDialog) fragment.onCreateDialog(fragment.getArguments());
    boolean showing = dialog.isShowing();

    //then
    assertFalse(showing);
}

}
```